# Pass the session name to the next activity in android

Tags: android

I have a scenario where after logging in through a login page, and I tried this solution to pass the session name to the homeactivity class.

In MainActivity class:

```
    progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,
            "start...", "welcome "
                    + rt2.getText().toString(), false,
            false);

    int secondsDelayed = 1;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    HomeActivity.class));

            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    HomeActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", rt2.getText()
                    .toString());
            Log.d("MainActivity.class", rt2.getText()
                    .toString());

            finish();
        }
    }, secondsDelayed * 1000);
```

In Home Activity class:

```
String name;
name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
Log.d("HomeActivity.class", name.toString());
```

I have the crash of android application, why?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `intent` Intent to start next `HomeActivity` Activity as:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("name", rt2.getText().toString());
 startActivity(intent);
```

Currently you are not passing `intent` with `name`  key to `startActivity`

Answer (score 0):

DO like this:-

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    HomeActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", rt2.getText()
                    .toString());
             startActivity(intent);
            Log.d("MainActivity.class", rt2.getText()
                    .toString());

            finish();
        }
    }, secondsDelayed * 1000);
```